# How do I create a "select folder OR file dialog window" in REALbasic?

Tags: realbasic

You can use

SelectFolder() to get a folder

or

GetOpenFolderitem(filter as string) to get files

but can you select either a folder or file? ( or for that matter selecting multiple files )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MonkeyBread plugin allows this in the OpenDialogMBS class.

http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.net/pluginhelp/navigation-opendialogmbs.shtml

```
OpenDialogMBS.AllowFolderSelection as Boolean
property, Navigation, MBS Util Plugin (OpenDialog), class OpenDialogMBS, Plugin version: 7.5, Mac OS X: Works, Windows: Does nothing, Linux x86: Does nothing, Feedback.

Function: Whether folders can be selected.
Example: 
dim o as OpenDialogMBS
dim i,c as integer
dim f as FolderItem

o=new OpenDialogMBS
o.ShowHiddenFiles=true
o.PromptText="Select one or more files/folders:"
o.MultipleSelection=false
o.ActionButtonLabel="Open files/folders"
o.CancelButtonLabel="no, thanks."
o.WindowTitle="This is a window title."
o.ClientName="Client Name?"
o.AllowFolderSelection=true
o.ShowDialog

c=o.FileCount
if c>0 then
  for i=0 to c-1
    f=o.Files(i)

    FileList.List.AddRow f.AbsolutePath
  next
end if


Notes: 
Default is false.
Setting this to true on Windows or Linux has no effect there.
(Read and Write property)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via any of the built-in APIs. There might be a plugin to do it, but I don't think there's OS support for it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but it's been included in recent versions. I'll put it here in case someone stumbles like me in this question:

[RealBasic Multiple Selection: OpenDialog.MultiSelect](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/OpenDialog.MultiSelect)

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you're using .Net I think you'll need to create your own control (or buy one).

Comment: the tag states I'm using realbasic